# Using USB to Serial in Ubuntu 12.04 - /dev/ttyUSB0 missing

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty, usbserial

I'm trying to connect a usb-serial adapter to Ubuntu 12.04 (on a VM). For some reason, there is no /dev entry for it.
I've tried several adapters from different manufacturers - With no success.

Also, I have a 10.04 VM on which I connect the adapter and it appears in /dev/ttyUSB0 immediately

I'm not a very proficient linux user. Do I need to install a driver of some sort?

Comment: Which adapter are you using? What is the lsusb output for it? Do you have a module in /lib/modules/<your-kernel>/kernel/drivers/usb/serial with similar name?

Comment: Check `dmesg` output also; it shows the kernel log which may have information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would disconnect it and tail syslog while connecting it again.  I have a USB to serial device that appears as something like /dev/ttyACM0 (I think.  I'm at work now), so look for /dev/ttyA*

Answer (score 1):

dmesg didn't change when I inserted / removed the usb, leading me to thing that udev (i think) 
is frozen.

Restarting the system fixed it.
(Obviously)

Sorry for wasting the cyber-space